# Java "Errors" with math - int vs Double

Tags: java, math, graph, int, double

I noticed something weird earlier today. I was writing some code that was supposed to make graphs in complex quadrants. Anyway, I typed `int i = 1/0;` and it wouldn't compile. When I changed the code to `double i = 1.0/0.0;` the code compiled fine. When I ran the code it gave an error / by 0. I was expecting that... But why does it compile fine when using doubles and not integers? I am using the Blue J IDE

Comment: They both compile fine for me, and the int version throws an error, which is expected behavior as far as I know. Are you sure you haven't gotten them mixed up in your head?

Comment: I think much better explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381544/why-doesnt-java-throw-an-exception-when-dividing-by-0-0

Comment: Also a third question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380499/is-this-declaration-possible/21380590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing an `int` value by zero would result in a `ArithmeticException`, hence the expression `1 / 0` is illegal.

The result of dividing a `double` value by zero is *infinity* or `NaN` *****, so the expression `1.0 / 0.0` is legal.

*) See t_over's comment for specifics:

Comment: Just to add.. Dividing a negative number by 0.0 equals negative infinity, and dividing zero by zero results in a Double.NaN

Comment: thanks @t_over i appreciate the extra clarification :)