# How to overwrite NaN or Infinity result when performing arithmetic on Double?

Tags: scala, floating-point, division

I'm running a calculation on a group of numbers and some of the results
of those calculations returns result of `NaN` or `Infinity`
After investigating I discovered that the root cause is because of
below arithmetic division :

```
object doublefun {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  val d1 = 0.0                                    //> d1  : Double = 0.0
  val d2 = 0.0                                    //> d2  : Double = 0.0

  val d = d1/d2                                   //> d  : Double = NaN

  val i1 = 1.0                                    //> i1  : Double = 1.0
  val i2 = 0.0                                    //> i2  : Double = 0.0

  val i = i1/i2                                   //> i  : Double = Infinity

  val o1 = 0                                      //> o1  : Int = 0
  val o2 = 0                                      //> o2  : Int = 0
  val o = o1/o2                                   //> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
}
```

I think asking why `NaN` and `Infinity` are returned in these cases is more of a
math question but it is interesting that `0/0` throws an `ArithmeticException`
while `0.0/0.0` does not ?

I'm using the result of these calculation to perform a sort descending : `NaN` & `Infinity`
results in elements appearing first when I require them to appear last.

How can I ensure that for any calculation which returns `NaN` or `Infinity` that
it appears last when sorted ? Can I check for `NaN` or `Infinity` within the result of 
the calculation and if it satisfies just assign to `0.0` :

```
if(d == Double.Infinity || d == Double.NaN){
  return 0.0
}
```

Comment: You cannot check for NaN this way because (NaN == NaN) returns false (!!!) Use `isNaN` and `isInfinite`.

Comment: You may also want to refer to [scala.Double](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind the use of `NaN` and not an exception is really a more general question, which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381633/2292812).

It's unclear how you're doing your sorting, but by default positive and negative infinity are in the correct sort order, and `NaN` comes last (in ascending order):

```
scala> List(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.NegativeInfinity, Double.NaN, 0.0, -1.0, 2.0).sorted
res15: List[Double] = List(-Infinity, -1.0, 0.0, 2.0, Infinity, NaN)
```

Any easy way to modify the behavior would be to map and match a list before sorting.

```
val list = List(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.NegativeInfinity, Double.NaN, 0.0, -1.0, 2.0)

list.map {
    case d if(d.isNaN) => 0.0 // Or whatever value you'd prefer.
    case d if(d.isNegInfinity) => 0.0 // Or whatever value you'd prefer.
    case d if(d.isPosInfinity) => 0.0 // Or whatever value you'd prefer.
    case d => d
}
```

In ascending order, `Double.NegativeInfinity` comes first, then all of the ascending real numbers, then `Double.PositiveInfinity` followed by `NaN`. If you want *both* `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity` as well as `NaN` to come last in descending order, then you could map them all to `Double.NegativeInfinity`.