# Dividing by zero in a boolean expression

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

I'm writing a program in Java, and I noticed that I had an expression in my code `x / y > 0` that was evaluating to `false` when `y == 0`. I have since corrected this line in my code, but I'm curious, does anyone know why `x / y > 0` evaluates to `false` rather than causing the program to terminate?

Comment: On my machine it throws ArithmeticException

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, if that matters.

Comment: I'm using eclipse too

Comment: Can you post your code. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java throw an Exception when dividing by 0.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381544/why-doesnt-java-throw-an-exception-when-dividing-by-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

`x / y` will throw `ArithmeticException` if they are both integers and y is 0.

`x / y` equals Infinity if they are floating point numbers.  And Infinity is greater than 0!

Comment: `Infinity` is greater than `0`, but that does not explain why `Infinity > 0 == false`. I suppose that not only `x,y` were floats and `y == 0`, but also `x < 0`.