# Zero division java integer vs double

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

```
    double doubleResult = 1d/0d;
    System.out.println(doubleResult);

    int intResult = 1/0;
    System.out.println(intResult);
```

The output is:

```
Infinity
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Why does double zero division returns Infinity and int zero division throws exception?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381544/why-doesnt-java-throw-an-exception-when-dividing-by-0-0).

Answer (score 1):

This is principally due to the fact that the `double` type (which in Java is an IEEE754 64 bit double precision type) has a representation for infinity, whereas an `int` type does not.

Note that `double doubleResult = 1 / 0;` would *still* cause an exception to be thrown: the type of the variable to which the result is assigned is not relevant.